# Picking random values multiple times from the same dict.

Tags: python

I'm trying to pick a random value from a dict. and then pick a second value from the same dict. guaranteeing that it is different.

```
def pick_value():
    value, attribute = random.choice(list(my_dict.items()))
    return(value, attribute)
```

If I call the function it works, however there is no guarantee that the second time I call it the value will be different than the first so I tried the following.

```
my_value_list = []

val1, attr1 = pick_value()
my_value_list.append(val1)

val2, attr2 = pick_value()
if val2 in my_value_list:
    val2, attr2 = pick_value()
```

I still get matching values occasionally. I tried replacing the `if val2 in` statement with `while val2 in` and still no luck. Am I misunderstanding something simple?

Comment: Do you need that dict for anything else after this operation?

Comment: Any reason you're not using `random.sample()`?

Comment: No, after I get my random values out it doesn't matter to me anymore.

Comment: he's probably going to suggest popping the value you grabbed to ensure uniqueness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need exactly two values (or any fixed number you know in advance), use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). That's what it's for: Sampling "without replacement", i.e. once you've picked an element from the list, it is no longer available to be picked again.

```
samples = random.sample(list(mydict.items()), 2)
attr1, val1 = samples[0]
attr2, val2 = samples[1]
```

Comment: That should do the work jsut perfect :D, thanks for sharing, great answer, short and sweet

Answer (score 2):

As `alexis` has suggested, `random.sample()` is the right tool for this job, but for the sake of completeness, if you need to pick up random fields in a iterative/lazy fashion, you can do it yourself by:

```
def pick_random_destructive(data):
    key = random.choice(data.keys()) if data else None
    return key, data.pop(key, None)
```

However, that WILL modify the `dict` you pass to it. If you want a non-modifying iterative method you can create a generator like:

```
def pick_random_nondestructive(data):
    keys = random.shuffle(data.keys())
    while keys:
        key = keys.pop()
        yield key, data[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

`random.choice` can achieve this but you'll be needing to retain state information after each call to the function as such when `random.choice` returns the previous random value, you ignore the value and call it again. Popping the value out of the sequence is another alternative:

```
def pick_value():
    L = list(my_dict.items())

    if hasattr(pick_value, 'prev'):
        for _ in range(100):
            res = random.choice(L)
            if res != pick_value.prev: 
                pick_value.prev = res
                return res
    else:
        res = random.choice(L)
        pick_value.prev = res
        return res
```

The first time you call `pick_value` there's no previous value, this is what the outer `if` statement is for, it checks if the there's a previous value and compare it against the newly chosen random value. This function  returns `None` when `random.choice` fails to return a random value that's not equal to the previous one after 100 calls to `random.choice`.

*Of course, this is just a variation on a theme, other users provided simpler alternatives, so you don't necessarily need to wrap `random.choice` with the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

This option is useful if you are already using numpy library:

Consider using random.choice from numpy:

```
import numpy as np

my_dict = {"a" : 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d" : 4}

#first, take two random key index from 0 to length
twoRandom = np.random.choice(list(my_dict.keys()),2,replace=False)

#then take the value of the key at index in the list
key1 = twoRandom[0]
key2 = twoRandom[1]

#finally, get the value
value1 = my_dict.get(key1)
value2 = my_dict.get(key2)
```

Comment: Your code samples with replacement, which is exactly what the OP wants to avoid. (And why are you sampling the indexes, and not the keys directly?)

Comment: Using a behemoth like NumPy to do simple sampling sounds awfully wasteful.

Comment: @alexis what is exactly the OP wants to avoid that I'm doing? I don't get you... my bad sorry, could you explain? And I'm sampling the index because I didn't know how to sample the values directly

Comment: @zwer using something like that solves your problem isn't bad, why reinvent the wheel? And how much is the cost to do an import?

Comment: The OP does not want repetitions in the results. To sample the values... just sample them :-) But actually the `len` you stuck in there will break your code, have you actually tried it?

Comment: I tryed what you said and it worked just fine, and really is more direct! Thanks a lot @alexis

Comment: @alexis right, I forget to add replace=False, that assure that it will be non Repeated values

Comment: That's better. :-) But I see numpy's `random.choice` does support an `int` first argument, I was wrong about that. Anyway now sample from `list(my_dict.items())`.

Comment: @DamianLattenero - NumPy adds 10-20MB to your Python install for starters - not everybody has it, nor has any use for it. NumPy import is rather slow as it has to build a ton of supporting accelerating structures. It's not about reinventing the wheel, it's about using the right tool for the job.

Comment: It&#39;s a valid point of view, I won&#39;t argue, it&#39;s true. I only tried to show another solution @zwer

Comment: @DamianLattenero - hey, don't get me wrong, the more solutions the merrier :)  I was just giving a comment that people should be aware of the 'cost' of using NumPy (a great module, btw.) for tasks that can be easily achieved without such shenanigans. If somebody is already using NumPy in their project there is `np.random.choice()` is far more versatile than the bundled `random.choice()`...

Comment: @zwer thanks, that's was my point, I wouldn't mention because is good to hear good critics without lose the mind haha, I wanted to accept what you said, because indeed you're right about it :), I didn't get you wrong, I'm not that arrogant

Comment: @zwer I added your observation to the answer